# Spring Boot Microservices load balancing vs cloud load balancing

Tags: spring-boot, cloud, microservices, load-balancing

I am new to Microservices. (Learning phase). I have a question. We deploy microservices at cloud. (e.g. AWS). Cloud already provide load balancing and logs. And We also implement Load Balancing(Ribbon) and logs(Rabbit MQ and Zipkin) in Spring Boot.
What is the difference in these two implementation? Do we need both?
Can some answer these questions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your title doesn't summarise your question, consider editing it in a way it conveys your question in high level. This will help others with similar questions to reach this thread quickly. This link might be useful - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Answer (score 1):

Ribbon is a client side load balancer which means there is no any other hop in between your client and service. Basically you keep and maintain a list of service on your client.

In AWS load balancer case you need to make another hop in between the client and server.

Both have advanges and disadvantages. Former has the advantage of not having any dependency to any specific external solution. Basically with ribbon and service discovery like eureka you can deploy your product to any cloud provider or on-premise setup without additional effort. Latter has advantage of not needing an extra component of service discovery or keeping the cache of service list on client. But it has that additional hop which might be an issue if you are trying to run an very high-load system.

Although I don't have much experience with AWS CloudWatch what I know is it helps you to collect logs to a central place from different AWS components. And that is what you are trying to do with your solution.

Comment: Thanks I get some idea at load balancing side. Still looking for some more info. Like Zipkin already provide logging. If I integrate Zipkin in microservice and deploy services at aws. How to collect zipkin logs. Since aws itself provide own logs, do we really need zipkin. Please provide some idea or link so I go through.                                                                                
 Thanks in advance